# Is having several desktop environments on one account bad?

Tags: 12.04, desktop-environments, compatibility

I have gnome classic, cinnamon, unity, gnome 3, and KDE installed on my only user account because I enjoy a little change from time to time (although my favorite is gnome classic) so I installed all of these desktop environments. I heard from a friend that it could potentially cause some problems. I was also told that it would be okay if I created a separate account for each environment, but I don't want to if I don't have to.

Any help is much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem that I see is that if you play with a lot of compiz settings, then you may find that these settings cause problems between (say) gnome classic and gnome3.  In past these kinds conflicts have mostly manifested themselves in the form of missing Unity Launchers and panels, requiring these settings to be reset to defaults.

If you do some research into where the settings for each environment are stored and whether or not compiz is even used, you should be able to head off any serious problems or at least have an understanding of why they have occurred.

I'd recommend that you pick an environment and stay with it, or use different users for each one so that the configurations files cannot conflict.  Since I actually do this frequently when testing development releases I know how much of pain changing users actually is, hence my recommendation to stay with one environment.